# (TailwindCSS) How do I make a column divider in a grid

Tags: grid, tailwind-css, divider

I want a divider to go between each of the columns of my grid like this:[image]

The divider should always be in the center of any two columns and should not be displayed on the outer edges of the grid. Note that the number of columns will change according to screen size. Any ideas how to do this?

Here is my code:
https://play.tailwindcss.com/ATXYuNgHg9

Answer (score 2):

You can try using a pseudo-element for the first red blocks, we make height  with very long with **vh** unit and hide it using the overflow property on the parent element.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<div class="absolute inset-0 justify-center p-32">
  <div class="grid gap-x-8 gap-y-3 overflow-hidden xs:grid-cols-1 sm:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-3 xl:grid-cols-4">
    <div class="relative w-30 h-10 bg-red-600 sm:after:content-[''] sm:after:absolute sm:after:w-[3px] sm:after:min-h-[500vh] sm:after:bg-black sm:after:right-[-1rem]"></div>
    <div class="relative w-30 h-10 bg-red-600 lg:after:content-[''] lg:after:absolute lg:after:w-[3px] lg:after:min-h-[500vh] lg:after:bg-black lg:after:right-[-1rem]"></div>
    <div class="relative w-30 h-10 bg-red-600 xl:after:content-[''] xl:after:absolute xl:after:w-[3px] xl:after:min-h-[500vh] xl:after:bg-black xl:after:right-[-1rem]"></div>
    <div class="w-30 h-10 bg-red-600"></div>
    <div class="w-30 h-10 bg-red-600"></div>
    <div class="w-30 h-10 bg-red-600"></div>
    <div class="w-30 h-10 bg-red-600"></div>
    <div class="w-30 h-10 bg-red-600"></div>
    <div class="w-30 h-10 bg-red-600"></div>
    <div class="w-30 h-10 bg-red-600"></div>
    <div class="w-30 h-10 bg-red-600"></div>
    <div class="w-30 h-10 bg-red-600"></div>
    <div class="w-30 h-10 bg-red-600"></div>
    <div class="w-30 h-10 bg-red-600"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```